# Is it possible to write common condition in one place and reuse it (in MyBatis)?

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

I have some queries inside `mapper.xml` which have almost the same condition. Is it possible to write the common part in one place and reuse it?

For example:

```
  select count(*) from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id;
```

Similarly I have another query:

```
  select id, name from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id;
```

I want to put `table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id;` in one place and reuse it in both queries.

Additionally I have something like:

```
<if test="id != 0">
    AND id = #{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}
</if>
<if test="assignTo != 0">
    AND assign_to = #{assignTo,jdbcType=INTEGER}
</if>
<if test="status != 0">
    AND status = #{status,jdbcType=INTEGER}
</if>
```

and this is also common in 2 queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use [SQL fragments](http://www.mybatis.org/core/sqlmap-xml.html#sql).**

For example, you can have:

```
<sql id="yourFragmentId1">
  table1 t1 inner join table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id;
</sql>
```

or

```
<sql id="yourFragmentId2">
  <if test="id != 0">
    AND id = #{id,jdbcType=INTEGER}
  </if>
  <if test="assignTo != 0">
    AND assign_to = #{assignTo,jdbcType=INTEGER}
  </if>
  <if test="status != 0">
    AND status = #{status,jdbcType=INTEGER}
  </if>
</sql>
```

and then, in your queries, refer to them with `<include refid="yourFragmentId1" />` and `<include refid="yourFragmentId2" />`, respectively.